# Кто первый добежит до финиша, тот и победил

Tags: синтаксис

> **Кто первый добежит до финиша**, тот и победил.

У меня два вопроса:

1. Чем является синтаксически "**Кто первый добежит до финиша**"? (я думаю одно большое подлежащее или определительное придаточное, но это наверняка неправильно)
2. Возможно это предложение оформить с тире? *Кто первый добежит до финиша - победил.*

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Это СПП с **местоименно-определительным придаточным** (по школьной классификации), здесь определяемым словом является не существительное, а местоимение (оно же указательное слово). Характерной особенностью таких предложений является то, что в них придаточное может стоять на первом месте, например: **Кто** смел, **тот** уверен в себе.

В предложениях такого типа указательные слова играют роль подлежащего, сказуемого или дополнения, соответственно различаются подлежащные, сказуемостные и объектные придаточные предложения.

**Кто** (союзное слово) **первый добежит до финиша**, **тот** (указательное слово) **и победил**. Здесь указательное местоименное слово "тот" в роли подлежащего,  а придаточное раскрывает его содержание.

2) **Кто первый добежит до финиша ― победил.** Тире ставится в неполном предложении.

Answer (score 0):

Что касается второго вопроса ( Кто первый добежит до финиша - победил), я думаю это неверно оформленное предложение, так как нарушена видо-временная связь между предложениями: добежит - будущее время, победил - прошедшее. Может быть, так - "Кто первый добежит до финиша, победиТ"?
А в первом предложении, я согласна с Sibylloi, "Кто первый добежит до финиша" - это определительное (или местоимённо - определительное) придаточное в СПП,  поскольку оно относится к местоимению ТОТ и отвечает на вопрос: тот - какой? или тот -  кто именно?

Comment: Думаю, что в исходной форме предложение тоже допустимо. Здесь условное сокращение смысла, полная формулировка которого была бы громоздкой: когда кто-то добежит до финиша первым, _будет считаться_ (в том же самом будущем), что он победил.

Comment: Согласна с Вами, Александр